# How can I solve the "Arrays have incompatible sizes" error when filtering an image using FFT in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the FFT of an array but I get an error: *"Arrays have incompatible sizes"*. How can I fix this problem? Here is my code:

```
% Read the image
im = imread('image2.jpg');

% Convert the image to double precision
im = im2double(im);

% Compute the FFT of the image
F = fft2(im);

% Define the filter mask
mask = [-1 -1 -1; -1 8 -1; -1 -1 -1];

% Filter the FFT using the mask
F_filtered = F .* fftshift(mask);

% Display the magnitude of the filtered FFT
imshow(log(abs(fftshift(F_filtered))), []); 

this error is coming 
Arrays have incompatible sizes for this operation.

Error in task3 (line 32)
F_filtered = F .* fftshift(mask);
```

Comment: `fftshift(mask)` has the same size as `mask`, i.e. `[3 3]`. What is the size of `im`? Hint: it's not `[3 3]`. Change `mask` to be the same size as `im`.

Answer (score 0):

```
F_filtered = F .* fftshift(mask);
```

In this line of code, you are trying to apply a mask filter to the Fourier Transform `F`.

The symbol `.*` means element-by-element multiplication of two matrices. So, as we are trying to multiply by position, the two matrices should have the same dimensions.

The `mask` here has dimensions `[3 3]` by definition. The `F` which is the fourier transform of `image2.jpg` may not have the same dimensions as `mask`, and thus, you are getting this error.

Please change `mask` to have same dimensions as the fourier transform of the image, and you should not get this error.

Hope this helps!